# Android: How reliable is getMacAddress() as unique identifier

Tags: android, wifi

Are there known bugs or issues with getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress() when it's used as a unique device identifier?

One of the alternatives, the Android ID, seems to be not available (or not really unique) on some tablets. FAIL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twmuBbC_oB8) from last year Google I/O, Reto Meier talked about exactly that problem off identifieng a device correctly.

For the solution you will have to watch the video, because I don't remember it anymore. But I do remember his concerns about the "MacAddress"-Solution. The problem about this solution his that it addresses a particular device and not a particular "installation", think of the problem when a user, who installed your app, sells his phone to another person which will also install your app. With the MacAddress you have no chance to distinct between those two ...

Comment: If the re-sold devices are the only problem, then i'd be happy. However, I fear a bit more, that any manufacturer or buggy modified android version is sending a zero address instead of unique IDs. or one does not provide this ID properly when there wifi turned off. All emulators that I have, return the ID properly, but i can never be sure...

Comment: Yeah, I think this zero-if-wifi-turned-off-thing is also what he mentioned in his talk. I highly encourage you to watch the video, because I'm pretty sure he gives a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem that I know of is that it is only available if Wi-Fi is enabled.

I think this is a big problem because some smartphone users probably never turn Wi-Fi on.  Your app can turn Wi-Fi on itself, but this means your app needs an additional permission "android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE".

Your general issue - how to uniquely identify the device - is widely discussed, e.g.

[Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id/2853253#2853253)

http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html